# How can I use a whole sphere image to texture a portion of a sphere in THREE.js?

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping

I'm simulating an earth using THREE.SphereGeometry with only 32x16 or 64x32 segments. It has very large flat spots several km deep. 1024x512 is nicer but not really an option. For the area I'm working in, I'd like to fill that area in with more segments so that the surface and the graphics match within centimeters.
I could use the phi and theta of SphereGeometry to define the portion I want...

But then I want to texture it. When I use the whole sphere texture for a portion, it squishes the whole image into that portion. Is there a way to just get the texture of the portion I want?
I'm new to UV mapping - are there options with that that can help?

This is more about geometry than level of detail. The LOD is very crude and I'm fine with that for now.

Comment: What’s wrong with applying a texture to your entire sphere? Do you have a screenshot of the problem? It might be easier to understand.

Comment: i do apply a texture to the whole sphere. i *also* want to have a portion of the texture applied to a portion of the sphere. this way i can get the "actual gps coordinates surface" and "graphics surface" to match. https://cubetronic.github.io